# What/where is "Nongsa Sensation" in Batam, Indonesia?

Tags: covid-19, where-on-earth, singapore, indonesia

Indonesia recently announced a travel bubble with Singapore, permitting travel to [Bintan Lagoi](https://www.bintan-resorts.com/) and, I quote,

> Nongsapura International Ferry Terminal for the travel bubble area in Nongsa Sensation in Batam ([source](https://www.indonesia.travel/gb/en/news/batam-bintan-travel-bubble-is-now-officially-open))

However, "Nongsa Sensation" turns up virtually no hits on Google.  My best guess is that it refers to [the peninsula near the ferry terminal](https://goo.gl/maps/BBYDYgdPWeJUvXGR8), but **what exactly is it**, and **where are the bubble boundaries**?

Comment: I think it's the trade name of the tourism association for the area near Nongsa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Nongsa Sensation adalah wadah perkumpulan pengelola resor dan golf di Nongsa Batam yang masuk dalam kawasan travel bubble.
>
> *Nongsa Sensation is an association for golf and resort managers in Nongsa Batam which is included in the travel bubble area.* (Google Translate)
>
> https://travel.tempo.co/read/1554711/travel-bubble-batam-bintan-singapura-disebut-masih-bahas-izin-kapal-jemputan

Since the travel bubble is limited to prebooked itineraries with a resort package, I would assume that members of this industry association are eligible for the bubble treatment. However, I was not able to find an official listing of its members.

In one news article though, it is listed as

> Dalam wilayah Nongsa Sensation ini, memiliki 4 resort dan 2 golf yang akan digunakan dalam Travel Bubble. Untuk resort, yakni, Montigo Resort, Batam View Resort, Nongsa Point Marina Resort dan Turi Beach Resort.
>
> "Untuk golf ada dua yaitu Tering Bay Golf, Palm Spring Golf," ujarnya.
>
> Ia menegaskan, wisman Singapura bisa menginap dan berlibur di resort yang telah disediakan. Setelah bermain golf, wisman harus kembali ke penginapan.
>
> *In the Nongsa Sensation area, there are 4 resorts and 2 golf courses that will be used in the travel bubble. For resorts, they are namely Montigo Resort, Batam View Resort, Nongsa Point Marina Resort and Turi Beach Resort.*
>
> *"For golf, there are two, namely Tering Bay Golf and Palm Spring Golf," he said.*
>
> *He asserted, Singaporean tourists can stay and vacation at the resorts that have been provided. After playing golf, tourists must return to the hotel.* (Google Translate)
>
> https://batam.tribunnews.com/2022/01/25/ketua-nongsa-sensation-kapal-pertama-dari-singapura-tiba-di-batam-28-januari-2022.